# Good works of Buddhist fiction?

Tags: books

Earlier this year I finished the [*Buddha* series by Osamu Tezuka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddha_(manga)), and really enjoyed it. I liked the blend of historical references with fictional dramatic elements (and the art, of course). I also read and enjoyed [Siddhartha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siddhartha_(novel)) in the past.

My question is: Can anyone recommend other similar pieces of Buddhist fiction? Fictional works with Buddhist themes, period fiction with a Buddhist element, or anything similar? (I've been reading so much serious material lately that I'd like to take a break with something a bit more relaxed.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I hope you don't mind my closing this as a duplicate. If other people have further answers to add, they should add them to that other question (so that all the answers are in one place). Also the two books you mention in this question would be good in answer to that question.

Comment: Don't mind at all! I searched before asking but somehow didn't find that one (no idea how I missed it). Thanks!